# How to leverage meanstack generator?

Tags: node.js, generator, mean-stack

I'm using meanstack generator to quickly scaffold my project. 
But I have a hard time just to figure out how to preview my app. 
I tried running "grunt server" to launch it, but failed.

And there is this complex folder structure generated. But there's 
no comprehensive guide to explain all the stuff.

Could someone gives me some lead to start? That'll be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron,  you have to start the Mongo server first:

get into the root directory of your application and type

-> `mongod`

*make a new tab in terminal*

-> `grunt serve`

this should fix your problem.

In terms of learning Meanstack there are a few videos on stack heres a video on folder structure [folders](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn22aK1J9PE) but I would suggest learning each piece individually instead of trying to jump the gun.  if you learn them individually and all the way through you will understand how they are pieced together.

Good luck.